# Where to create the file app.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, web-applications

In the [Azure tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/), the step 4 says "Create an app.js file to implement the basic mobile server". But in my `node_modules\azure-mobile-apps\generator\app\templates\server` directory there is already an `app.js` file, which makes me confused. I'm new to this and I have no idea in which folder I should create the `app.js` file.

I appreciate any help you guys can offer. And any suggestion about learning Node.js as a beginner?

Thank you

Comment: The app.js file is usually the initial file to a NodeJS app. It can have another name as well, as server.js, which is also very common. The location should be your app root folder. The folder node_modules is specific to libraries installed with npm. It doesn't make sense to have your app.js there. I think you should place your app.js file in the root folder and adapt it to what the tutorial says. Also, the github page to create a basic app in Azzure (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/tree/master/samples/basic-app) correctly doesn't even version the folder node_modules.

Comment: @Tom Thank you so much for your detailed explanation and the correction you made on the format.